# Coolant Level Sensor Connector Replacement

Tags: electrical, vw, wiring, sensor, connector

I'm looking for a replacement male connector to fit this [coolant level sensor](http://www.partsplaceinc.com/products/product-detail.aspx?sku=9066) from a 1989 VW Jetta. Finding replacement sensors is straightforward, but what does one do when repairing a missing connector?

[image: coolant level sensor connector]

Comment: I usually look on rockauto.com for parts like this, but even so, they don't have one either. Your *best bet* is to go to a wrecking yard and find one. A pick-a-part would have the plug I have no doubt. Bring a pair of diagonal cutters and you should be golden. Looking at what the sensor was used in, there are a ton of vehicles which would have the connector in it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, Can you describe how to look up the sensor to find other vehicles – is it search on VW Jetta 1989 coolant level and then find a non-VW source to see other applications?

Comment: The sensor fits several VWs up through the late 90s.  Goto rockauto.com, find your vehicle, find the sensor, click on the part number.

Comment: Have you asked a VW dealership? A lot of times they may not import or charge stupid-high prices but sometimes they bring stuff at decent prices..

Comment: I have not tried a dealer, perhaps that'll be my next move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for an exact match seems to be a salvage yard, at least so far.

However, I was recently looking for a replacement connector for the coolant temperature sensor and noticed that the connector looks very similar to the coolant level sensor, so I ordered two. It's not an exact fit as the retaining mechanism doesn't click securely into place, but it's a solid electrical connection and more robust than two spade terminals.

http://www.rockauto.com/?carcode=1283116&parttype=2564
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions in comments:

Let's say that disaster strikes and not a single usable connector remains in the world.

You can still wire up or solder something as simple as this. You will need to figure out the polarity to understand which wire goes to which terminal and ensure that the two wires cannot cross one another.

Comment: This is the approach I'm currently using, two female spade terminals carefully pressed onto the tabs so they don't short each other.